# Returning message instead of null in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using a CASE statement to return Morning, Evening or Not Yet closed on basis of comparison. It works best but not for 'Not Yet Closed'. It returns null which I don't want. I want if no closing date has been inserted then it should return 'Not Yet Closed' instead of NULL.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Report_SelectComplaintsByShift] 

    @IsMorningEvening bit

AS
BEGIN

    Begin Try

      Select ComplaintID, ComplaintSubject, Complainants.ComplainantName as Complainant,
       Case When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) < 17) then 'Morning'
       When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) >= 17) then 'Evening' 
       When ( Complaints.ClosingDateTime = '' ) then 'Not Closed Yet'
       End as ClosingShift
      from Complaints Inner Join Complainants 
      ON Complaints.Complainant_ID = Complainants.ComplainantI

END
```

Comment: Did you get result with `'Not Closed Yet'` anytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use **`Else`** in your case statement.

```
  Select ComplaintID, ComplaintSubject, Complainants.ComplainantName as Complainant,
         Case 
            When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) < 17) then 'Morning'
            When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) >= 17) then 'Evening' 
            Else 'Not Closed Yet'
         End as ClosingShift
  from Complaints 
  Inner Join Complainants ON Complaints.Complainant_ID = Complainants.ComplainantI
```

If you want to check your query with NULL Value use following query:

```
  Select ComplaintID, ComplaintSubject, Complainants.ComplainantName as Complainant,
         Case 
            When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) < 17) then 'Morning'
            When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) >= 17) then 'Evening' 
            When (Complaints.ClosingDateTime IS NULL) Then 'Not Closed Yet'
         End as ClosingShift
  from Complaints 
  Inner Join Complainants ON Complaints.Complainant_ID = Complainants.ComplainantI
```

Comment: yes sir but i must have to define Condition too like if = null then 'This'

Comment: You must use IS NULL Instead of = null on your query.

Answer (score 4):

You check with **`IS NULL`** and **`ELSE`** part:

Try like this

```
  Select ComplaintID, ComplaintSubject, Complainants.ComplainantName as Complainant,
         Case 
            When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) < 17) Then 'Morning'
            When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) >= 17) Then 'Evening' 
            When (Complaints.ClosingDateTime IS NULL ) Then 'Not Closed Yet'
            ELSE 'Not Closed Yet'
         End as ClosingShift
  from Complaints 
  Inner Join Complainants ON Complaints.Complainant_ID = Complainants.ComplainantI
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use `(Complaints.ClosingDateTime = '')` condition first in your `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT  ComplaintID, ComplaintSubject, Complainants.ComplainantName AS Complainant,
        CASE    WHEN (Complaints.ClosingDateTime IS NULL OR Complaints.ClosingDateTime = '') THEN 'Not Closed Yet'
                WHEN (DATEPART(HOUR, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) < 17) THEN 'Morning'
                WHEN (DATEPART(HOUR, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) >= 17) THEN 'Evening' 
        END AS ClosingShift
FROM    Complaints INNER JOIN
        Complainants ON Complaints.Complainant_ID = Complainants.ComplainantID
```

Actually, if `Complaints.ClosingDateTime = ''` then `DATEPART(HOUR, Complaints.ClosingDateTime)` is **0**. So `(DATEPART(HOUR, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) < 17)` condition satisfied and you will get the result **'Morning'**.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using **COALESCE** to avoid null.
I suppose following should work

```
  Select ComplaintID, ComplaintSubject, Complainants.ComplainantName as Complainant,
  COALESCE (( Case When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) < 17) then 'Morning'
   When (datepart(hour, Complaints.ClosingDateTime) >= 17) then 'Evening' 
   When ( Complaints.ClosingDateTime = '' ) then 'Not Closed Yet'
   End),'Not Closed Yet') as ClosingShift
  from Complaints Inner Join Complainants 
  ON Complaints.Complainant_ID = Complainants.ComplainantI
```